# Evaluating false in bash with multiple commands without a subshell

Tags: bash, shell-script, sh

Bash evaluates the logical operators such that && always takes precedence. So for example:

```
false || echo 1 && echo 2
1
2
```

and

```
true || echo 1 && echo 2
2
```

Ok. So lets say I want the output to be like this:

```
false || (echo 1 && echo 2)
```

But without invoking a subshell.

The only solution I could think of is this:

```
false || if true; then echo 1; echo 2; fi
1
2
```

Is there any cleaner way, similar to parenthesis in C, to group commands together without having to invoke a subshell?

Comment: In retrospect, this should probably have been posted on stackoverflow.

Comment: No, it's also fine to ask here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
false || { echo 1 && echo 2; }
```

Comment: This seems to be accurate. No parallel processing subshell is created when I do this: `{ sleep 0.2s; echo 1; } || { echo 1 && echo 2; }`